# What Would be A Good Design Theme for PMSE?

Tags: discussion

When the site moves out of beta, the SE designers will work on building a CSS theme and a logo for the site.

Assuming the site continues to grow as it has, what would be a good design theme for the PMSE site?  What should the logo look like?  What colors should be used?

**UPDATE:**

The site has seen an increase in traffic in the last two weeks. Let's start thinking more about what elements should appear in the final, non-sketchy version of the design.

What colors should we suggest the design team uses? What themes? What should *definitely not* be here?

**NOTE:  Remember that downvotes work different on meta and do not affect reputation. Please downvote ideas you disagree with, and upvote those you support. The votes will help the designer determine what our community prefers.**

Comment: So we "made it"? I see that visitors per day is now in the mid-400s.

Comment: @ashes999 - I'm confident that we will eventually leave beta; however, I don't think we're quite there yet. Some betas extend for 6 months to a year before the site finally meets enough of the metrics to graduate. Our numbers are improving, and more traffic *is* coming from search engines, but we still need more time to get this site up to the same level as other sites that have launched and left beta.

Comment: that's awesome. I thought it's "shape up in 90 days or ship out."

Comment: @Ashes - Check out this blog post: [When Will My Site Graduate?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/). Basically, as long as the site continues to show signs of growth and good quality, we can remain in beta indefinitely until all the metrics are exceeded. So keep up the good efforts in positively contributing to this site! We have a fantastic community here :)

Comment: I just wanted to use "chartreuse" in a sentence. :)

Comment: @CodeGnome - Interesting color choice, both visually as well as auditory.

Comment: Can we please not use Gantt charts? They just might be one of the most poorly used tools in a PM's toolbox...

Comment: Hi @aclear16, if you have an idea instead of Gantt charts, please feel free to post an answer. Nothing is finalized yet, and the designer won't start working on this until the community managers feel like our site is ready for launch. One of the goals for launch is increasing meta activity and more community participation in governing the site, so thank you for weighing in! ;)

Comment: How about something more agile oriented, like a Kanban board or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, the Theme for PMSE should have the origin of Project Management and it should include great persons who contributed for Project Management evolutiuon, like [Frederick Taylor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_Winslow_Taylor), [Henri Fayol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Fayol) and [Herny Gantt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Gantt), etc.

Despite using references to former personalities, colors should bring the **modern** and **clear** aspect to the site.

The logo should be something that represents a day-by-day work of a project manager.

Something you would easily identify as a project management icon.

Could be something analogue to the stack overflow logo, or maybe something else like [this picture](http://www.takttime.net/wp-content/uploads/change-management.jpg)

**How to mix all theses ideas together in a good looking site?**

Still couldn't figure it out, but if I do, I'll post it here.

Comment: What do you think about using faded out pictures of those three contributors in the corners of the site?  I'm not sure about the yellow construction picture because it makes me think the site is "under construction", but I do like where you're going with this.

Comment: That's exactly what is in my mind!(regarding to the faded out pictures). Regarding the logo I'm thinking in some analogue picture that represents a project manager as leader of a team, driving people to the right way. It could be like [husk-Siberian dogs](http://www.alaskaphotographics.com/search/photos/ak1ds-11635.jpg) that always have a leader dog to drive the way.

Comment: Are there any creative-commons photos of the people that you have access to?  If you include them in your answer, we can recommend them to the StackExchange design team :)

Comment: @jmort253 - Unfortunately, I don't. I'll talk to a friend of mine that maybe can help.

Answer (score 1):

How about something which represents process and results? Ultimately, project management is about applying knowledge and experience to a process to improve the results or the process itself..

Comment: I like this idea because it's not specific to any one methodology, and it's broad enough to where it would give the designer some freedom to go in different directions.

Answer (score 0):

**[Frederick Taylor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_Winslow_Taylor)**:

[image: Frederick Taylor]

---

**[Henri Fayol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Fayol)**
[image: Henri Fayol]

---

**[Henry Gannt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Gantt)**
[image: Henry Gannt]

Comment: I also think that images of Gannt charts could fit here.  I also picture a single individual depicted in a communication graph using different means of communication (phone, email, Skype, face to face) to communicate with different people who are also using these technologies to communicate with other individuals.

Answer (score 0):

I am supporting simple Gantt chart. Will definitely give the meaning to visitors.

**Examples:**

Textless gantt:
[image]

Gantt:
[image]

Phone gantt and pie chart:
[image]

Simple gantt bar:
[image]